# Eclipse failed to load MyFirstApp after uploading it to the emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

```
[2014-05-28 23:45:49 - MyFirstApp] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-05-28 23:45:49 - MyFirstApp] Uploading MyFirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-05-28 23:45:54 - MyFirstApp] Installing MyFirstApp.apk...
[2014-05-28 23:48:22 - MyFirstApp] Failed to install MyFirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-05-28 23:48:22 - MyFirstApp] (null)
[2014-05-28 23:48:24 - MyFirstApp] Launch canceled!
```

This is only part of the output while the emulator is configuring. I've not gotten it to run the app for any of steps from the beginning of the training process on "developer.android.com" The emulator starts just fine, but when it comes to doing this part of the process it always fails. I've tried everything that I can think of, but nothing works. By the way, I'm doing this on a Viao xp home laptop. I checked to see where the MyFirstApp.apk file is being placed and it is in the bin folder. I've installed all of the latest SDKs. I've got the latest version of Eclipse for Java programmers. There are no errors in the code that I can see. And neither does the compiler. I've tried different AVDs and it always fail to install the apk after uploading. I've even deleted the app several times only to get the same result. I also performed Derek Banas' tutorial on Fixing android problems and nothing worked.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Is it possible that my xp OS is just too old? I will accept any and all assistance. Thanks for your support! By the way I'm a novice. But I read very well.

Comment: Did you enable usb debugging?

Comment: Can you post your full LogCat?